# Clicking on div triggers all elements with class name

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have 2 divs in my website. One with attribute clickDisabled and other with out.
I am trying to click on a div and it should show warning only if its attribute has clickDisabled. But in my case both the div clicks show alert. How can I limit showing alert message to only one div with attribute clickDisabled?

```
<div> 
       <img title="You cannot edit." class="editMe" src="/Content/Images/edit.png" clickdisabled="disable">  
</div>

    <div>
        <img title="You cannot edit." class="editMe" src="/Content/Images/edit.png">
    </div>


 if ($('.editMe').attr('clickdisabled') == 'disable') {
        alert('warning');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Use `clickdisabled` instead of `clickDisabled` in the Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$(this)` instead of `$('.editMe')` because the statement below is always going to return true

```
if ($('.editMe').attr('clickdisabled') == 'disable')
```

because it checks for every element which has class `editMe`. So it will return true once it find the first element even when you clicked on second one.

Here is the code you can try with

```
$('.editMe').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('clickdisabled') == 'disable') {
        alert('warning');
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ww8pfsf/)